# Using downloaded wget

Tags: wget

I downloaded the source code of `wget` using `apt-get source wget`. I want to modify it a little, then use this `wget` rather than the one I'm using in `/usr/bin/wget`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`apt-get source wget` is retrieving your distribution's source code of `wget`.

You may want to work on the genuine upstream `wget` source, which you can get (with some `wget` or some browser) by following links from http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/

Then you configure, build and install - usually with `./configure; make; sudo make install` but the details may vary from package to package. You should look into files named `README` and `INSTALL`

You could also be interested by [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/)

Notice that the [GPL](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html) license requires more or less that you publish your patch (in source form) if you redistribute your patched version of your improved `wget` software binary

Comment: Thanks. When you say "the details may vary from package to package", where can I find the details for each package? I cannot find installation instructions in the `README` file.

Comment: Oh, didn't see that file. Thanks!